Почему во vue в nginx.conf обращаясь к одной секции он обращается к другой секции?
есть вот такой конфигурационный файл
server {
 listen 3000;
 server_name _;

 gzip on;
 gzip_static on;
 gzip_buffers 4 16k;
 gzip_comp_level 2;
 gzip_vary off;
 gzip_disable "MSIE [1-6]\.";
 gzip_min_length 100;
 gzip_types text/plain text/css text/xml text/javascript application/x-javascript 
    application/xml application/json;
 gzip_disable "MSIE [1-6]\.";

 root /usr/share/nginx/html;

 charset utf-8;
 index   index.html index.htm;

 location ~ \.(?:jpg|jpeg|js|css|gif|png|swf|ico)$ {
   #expires        5d;
   access_log     off;
   add_header Pragma public;
   add_header Cache-Control "public, must-revalidate, proxy-revalidate";
 }

 location / {
   root /usr/share/nginx/html;
   try_files $uri /index.html;
 }

 location = /index.html {
   internal;
   add_header Cache-Control 'no-store';
 }

 location /auth-api/ {
   proxy_pass  https://$AUTH_URL/api/;
   proxy_redirect off;
   proxy_ssl_protocols TLSv1.2 TLSv1.3;
   proxy_set_header X-Real-IP  $remote_addr;
   proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
   proxy_intercept_errors  off;
   proxy_buffer_size       4k;
   proxy_buffers           4 32k;
   proxy_busy_buffers_size 64k;
   proxy_temp_file_write_size 64k;
   proxy_read_timeout 120;
   proxy_connect_timeout 120;
   client_max_body_size 20M;
 }

 location /api/ {
   proxy_pass  https://$BACKEND_URL/api/;
   proxy_redirect off;
   proxy_ssl_protocols TLSv1.2 TLSv1.3;
   proxy_set_header X-Real-IP  $remote_addr;
   proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
   proxy_intercept_errors  off;
   proxy_buffer_size       4k;
   proxy_buffers           4 32k;
   proxy_busy_buffers_size 64k;
   proxy_temp_file_write_size 64k;
   proxy_read_timeout 120;
   proxy_connect_timeout 120;
   client_max_body_size 20M;
 }

}
и
const urls = {
 users: "/auth-api/v1/user",
 roles: "/auth-api/v1/role",
};

запросы users и roles должны отправляться на location /auth-api/ но почему то он отправляет на location /api/ и из-за этого у меня выдает 404 page not found, как вы понял у меня в vue 2 разных бэкенда, $AUTH_URL и $BACKEND_URL это url бэкенда (https://бэкенд/api/...). Кто нибудь сталкивался с такой проблемой?
